# How do you increase the height of a <div> to align with others in the row?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm currently building a website, it's an e-commerce site, and I'm currently stuck at the actual store building part. The relevant code is as follows:

```css
.storeItems{
    display: inline-flex;
    padding-top: 5%;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-right: 10%;
    align-items: stretch;
    padding-left: 2%;
    padding-right: 2%;
}
.storeitem{
    padding-top: 1%;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color:#c1d8ee;
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: stretch;
    text-align: center;
    width: 20%;
    height: 30%;
}
.storeitem:hover{
    opacity: 0.5;
}
.productImage{

    display: inline-flex;
    text-align: center;
    align-self: center;
    width: 90%;
    height: 75%;
}   
.productTitle{
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}
.productPrice{
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="storeItems"> <!-- The store item, containing an image, the title of the item and the price.-->
    <div class="storeitem">
        <a class="product" href="productPage.html"><img class="productImage" src="img/book.png"></a>
        <div class="productInfo">
            <h2 class="productTitle">SEAFRET Book</h1>
            <h2 class="productPrice">$14.99</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="storeitem">
        <a class="product" href="productPage.html"><img class="productImage" src="img/bundle.png"></a>
        <div class="productInfo">
            <h2 class="productTitle">SEAFRET Bundle</h2>
            <h2 class="productPrice">$30.00</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="storeitem">
        <a class="product" href="productPage.html"><img class="productImage" src="img/sweater.png"></a>
        <div class="productInfo">
            <h2 class="productTitle"> SEAFRET Sweater</h2>
            <h2 class="productPrice">$15.99</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="storeitem">
        <a class="product" href="productPage.html"><img class="productImage" src="img/totebag.png"></a>
        <div class="productInfo">
            <h2 class="productTitle"> SEAFRET Totebag</h2>
            <h2 class="productPrice">$15.99</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Firstly, I'm very aware of how terribly my code reads, and I'm very sorry for that, I'm not at all familiar with the coding standards for HTML or CSS. I'm also aware it's very likely that much of my CSS is redundant because I'm using flexbox, but I don't know which parts are and are not useful, and I don't want to break it again, so for now I'm leaving it.

This code gives me the following:
[image: Image of code out put on the website]

and as you can see the middle two tiles aren't as long as the outer two, so how would I go about making the two middle ones taller. The design needs to be **responsive** so that it can be resized, so I'm pretty sure it's not as simple as just increasing the height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is remove the width and height from the store item class – that's what's shrinking it down.

Also, you might want to consider using CSS Grid for this application – Let me know if you want to know how to do that!

```css
.storeItems{
    display: inline-flex;
    padding-top: 5%;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-right: 10%;
    align-items: stretch;
    padding-left: 2%;
    padding-right: 2%;
}
.storeitem{
    padding-top: 1%;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color:#c1d8ee;
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: stretch;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 1em;
    padding: 1em;
}
.storeitem:hover{
    opacity: 0.5;
}
.productImage{

    display: inline-flex;
    text-align: center;
    align-self: center;
    width: 90%;
    height: 75%;
}   
.productTitle{
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}
.productPrice{
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="storeItems"> <!-- The store item, containing an image, the title of the item and the price.-->
    <div class="storeitem">
        <a class="product" href="productPage.html"><img class="productImage" src="img/book.png"></a>
        <div class="productInfo">
            <h2 class="productTitle">SEAFRET Book</h1>
            <h2 class="productPrice">$14.99</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="storeitem">
        <a class="product" href="productPage.html"><img class="productImage" src="img/bundle.png"></a>
        <div class="productInfo">
            <h2 class="productTitle">SEAFRET Bundle</h2>
            <h2 class="productPrice">$30.00</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="storeitem">
        <a class="product" href="productPage.html"><img class="productImage" src="img/sweater.png"></a>
        <div class="productInfo">
            <h2 class="productTitle"> SEAFRET Sweater</h2>
            <h2 class="productPrice">$15.99</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="storeitem">
        <a class="product" href="productPage.html"><img class="productImage" src="img/totebag.png"></a>
        <div class="productInfo">
            <h2 class="productTitle"> SEAFRET Totebag</h2>
            <h2 class="productPrice">$15.99</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'd love know how to use a grid, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

The grid method:

Grid allows you to set template columns – and allow you to set the width of the child items to one unit of free space. It's the most modern way of doing layouts – and unlike flex, it's capable of 2D (rows and columns) manipulation.

```css
.storeItems{
    display: grid;
    padding: 5% 2%;
    margin: 0 10%;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    grid-gap: 1em;
}
.storeitem{
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color:#c1d8ee;
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: stretch;
    text-align: center;
}
.storeitem:hover{
    opacity: 0.5;
}
.productImage{

    display: inline-flex;
    text-align: center;
    align-self: center;
    width: 90%;
    height: 75%;
}   
.productTitle{
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}
.productPrice{
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="storeItems"> <!-- The store item, containing an image, the title of the item and the price.-->
    <div class="storeitem">
        <a class="product" href="productPage.html"><img class="productImage" src="img/book.png"></a>
        <div class="productInfo">
            <h2 class="productTitle">SEAFRET Book</h1>
            <h2 class="productPrice">$14.99</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="storeitem">
        <a class="product" href="productPage.html"><img class="productImage" src="img/bundle.png"></a>
        <div class="productInfo">
            <h2 class="productTitle">SEAFRET Bundle</h2>
            <h2 class="productPrice">$30.00</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="storeitem">
        <a class="product" href="productPage.html"><img class="productImage" src="img/sweater.png"></a>
        <div class="productInfo">
            <h2 class="productTitle"> SEAFRET Sweater</h2>
            <h2 class="productPrice">$15.99</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="storeitem">
        <a class="product" href="productPage.html"><img class="productImage" src="img/totebag.png"></a>
        <div class="productInfo">
            <h2 class="productTitle"> SEAFRET Totebag</h2>
            <h2 class="productPrice">$15.99</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this, you've really saved me a lot of time here